# Next and prev slide

Tags: jquery, html, animation

I have the following html -

```
<div id='slides'>
                <div id='slide1'>Slide1!</div>
                <div id='slide2'>Slide2!</div>
                <div id='slide3'>Slide3!</div>
</div>
```

I am able to slide between the divs by using this technique with three buttons `btnSlide1, btnSlide2, btnSlide3` -

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnSlide1', function (e) {

    var slideW = $('#slides').width();

    e.preventDefault();
    $('#slides').animate({ scrollLeft: slideW }, 600);


});
```

And then either add or minus `slideW` depending on which button is clicked.

This works fine however as the numbers of slides increase this does not really scale, so what I would prefer is a next and previous button instead of individual buttons for individual slides.

My problem is with only two buttons the context of `slideW` is no longer valid as I dont know which slide I am on at the time of the button click.

Is there a way to do this with just a next and prev option? I have tried to -

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnNext', function (e) {

    $('#slides').animate({ Left: '100%' }, 600);


});
```

However this resulted in the first slide partially moving left.

Current [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9tno043/)

Comment: can you create a fiddle so we can have a look at it rather than we creating one?

Comment: @bipen added the jfiddle

Comment: Are your slides all the same width?

Comment: yes sir @nils they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have kept your HTML/CSS, and just added `var current` to track current slide.

```
slideW = $('#slides').width();
current = 0;
$(document).on('click', '#prev', function(e) {

  if (current > 0 && current <= $('#slides').children().length - 1) {
    current--;
  }

  console.log(current);
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#slides').animate({
    scrollLeft: slideW * current - 100
  }, 600);

});

$(document).on('click', '#next', function(e) {

  if (current < $('#slides').children().length - 1)
    current++;
  console.log(current);
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#slides').animate({
    scrollLeft: slideW * current + 100
  }, 600);

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/86he7L41/1/

Of course, there are conditions to prevent undesired scrolling: left, or right - number of slides is limit.